# importing a class in intellij with circular dependency in java

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am working with a java project, i wanted to import a public class in it but it did not showed up with any of the other classes. So i figured out that we need to add dependency of the module where the class is in order to do so. On doing so it gave the warning of circular dependency.

I accepted the warning. then it gave the list of classes to import from. One of which was the class i wanted, I clicked on it but nothing happens. back to beginning.

i mean it should add, when it gives the option of adding it so after accepting warning, is’nt it ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [MySQL Workbench](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import-table.html) here you can customize columns as well.

Another way is that read CSV file using java and create insert statements by iterating CSV columns here also you can customize